# word to describe rising against?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that would mean or can be used to describe rising against someone or something, either from a force/people/trials?

Comment: Are you asking for a verb or an adjective?  A word to *describe* that would be "rebellious" or "revolutionary," but a word that means to *do* that would be "revolt" or "rebel."  You should provide an example sentence for context.

Comment: Please provide context.

Answer (score 2):

The word that works best should be "[**revolt**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolt)":

> to act in a way that shows that you do not accept the control or
>   influence of someone or something

Also, check the following synonyms mentioned along with that [definition of revolt in MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolt):

> insurgence, insurgency, insurrection, mutiny, outbreak, rebellion, revolution, rising, uprising

Comment: @MAP, thanks for pointing out. I originally copied the wrong list. Have corrected it now. My bad!